# False negative with address sanitizer?

Tags: address-sanitizer, sanitizer

Consider the code below. No error is shown when I compile and run it with address sanitizer. But there should be an error right i.e assigning/accessing out of bounds memory location? Why doesn't address sanitizer detect it?

```
int arr[30];

int main(){
    arr[40] = 34;
    printf(“%d”, arr[40]);
}
```

Thanks!

```
clang -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer test.c
./a.out
```

Answer (score 3):

This is described by the following entry in [FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#faq):

```
Q: Why didn't ASan report an obviously invalid memory access in my code?

A1: If your errors is too obvious, compiler might have already optimized it 
    out by the time Asan runs.

A2: Another, C-only option is accesses to global common symbols which are
    not protected by Asan (you can use -fno-common to disable generation of
    common symbols and hopefully detect more bugs).
```

Comment: But even if I make int arr[30] local, instead of global, it does not throw an error. Even using -fno-common is not throwing an error.

Comment: Sure, that's what answer A1 is about. Basically GCC frontend is "clever" enough to throw away obviously bad access early, before ASan has a chance to intervene.